# How to use a google script web app with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, web-applications, publish

I deployed a web app using google apps script and when I try to make requests to it using `Node.js` I get the following error:

> Google Drive Page Not Found - Sorry, unable to open the file at this time

But everything works fine when I'm sending the requests using `Postman`.

This is my node.js code:

```
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'gzip': true,
    'accept': '*/*',
    'content-length': 0,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'url': 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/script-id/exec'
  }
  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
```

This is the content of the google apps script web app:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({success: true}));
}
```

There are a couple more questions related to this topic, but the solution they provide is to remove `/u/#` from the URL ... which does not apply in my case.

Could this happen because I'm making requests from a `http` server to a web app deployed on `https`? That's the only thing that I'm thinking of...

---

**Update:**
I've also tried to send the request from a `HTTPS` node server and it still doesn't work.
Making a `GET` request works fine.

Comment: I'm sure that the ID is correct and yes, the script has a `doPost()` function. It's weird that I can make requests from Postman, but not from a Node.js server

Comment: I've added the code of the google apps script to the question body. Postman is just a tool that you can use to make requests, for example, I also tried on http://www.apirequest.io/ and it works there too.

Comment: It seems your nodejs request is just `GET`ting instead of POSTing.. Try adding uppercase ``POST``.. or ``request.post(options, ..)`` or adding headers like `Accept:*/*`, user-agent  etc.

Comment: It actually sends a `POST` request, I checked that in the Network tab. I've added those headers, but still getting the same error. It seems that making `GET` requests work fine, I can't find the reason why the `POST` requests are failing...

Comment: I see you updated your post. Shouldn't  headers be inside options? `options={headers:{Accept:"*/*"}}`

Comment: That's correct, my bad. I'll add an answer with the solution, thank you for helping me on this!

Answer (score 2):

Making `POST` requests from a `Node.js` server to a web app deployed using `Google Apps Script` requires the `'Content-Length'` header to be specified, and also the `followAllRedirects` option set to `true`, which is needed because the initial request is a redirect to another request that returns the response.

The working code looks like this:

```
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'gzip': true,
    'body': [],
    'followAllRedirects': true,
    'headers': {
      'Content-Length': 0 // length of the specified `body`
    },
    'url': 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec'
  }

  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
```

Hopefully this will help others that are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing the web app inside Google Apps Script, make sure you have set the "Who has access" option to "Anyone, including anonymous".

Also, it may not work if your organization does not allow sharing of Drive files outside the organization. This setting can only be [changed](https://ctrlq.org/code/20282-publish-google-script-web-app) by the GSuite admin.

Comment: The "Anyone, including anonymous" is selected. I think that there has to be some headers that I need to add because making a `GET` request works fine.